# Accidentally used patio paint on basement floor

Tags: basement

Accidentally painted patio paint instead of drylok on basement floor, can on paint a a second coat using drylok on top of patio paint?

Comment: Are you thinking that Drylok is the only acceptable finish for basement floors, and if so, why do you think that? Do you have a moisture problem with the basement floor?

Comment: oh man, you need to burn down the house and start over. Just kidding, patio paint should be fine. Check the directions to see about 2nd coat compatibility with different 1st layer paints if needed, but i would just use more patio paint if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. No, I have a small moisture problem. House is 25 years old. Looking to finish half the basement and want to start with a good base just in case.